# Equivalent of gCentroid(x, byid=FALSE) in sf system?

Tags: r, sf

I am attempting to change a number of scripts from the sd world to the sf world and am running across a problem that I feel really should have a simple solution (and probably does; I just can't find it!).

What should one do in sd to find the centroid of a collection of polygons; i.e. the equivalent of gCentroid?

Specifically, I have a file of all the counties of a state from tigris and would like to, using that file, calculate the centroid of the state.

Comment: I have found a workaround using      mp <- sf::st_union(Counties.crop);
      center <- sf::st_centroid(mp)

Comment: It is not a workaround -- that is one of possible solutions...

Comment: Good to know, thanks!